# Could someone please go through this code line by line and explain it in Pseudocode or English

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
try:
    number = input('Enter') #Asks user to input 7 digit number

    if len(str(number)) != 7:
        print('Incorrect')
    if len(str(number)) == 7:
        print('Okay')
        multiplier = [3,1]
        times = ''
        total = 0
        for index, digit in enumerate(list(str(number))):
            total = total + int(digit)*multiplier[index%2]
            times = times+str(int(digit)*multiplier[index%2])+', '
        mof10 = total + (10 - total%10)
        checkdigit = mof10 - total
        final = str(number) + str(checkdigit)
        print (times[:-1])
        print(total)
        print(mof10)
        print(checkdigit)
        print(final)
        break
except ValueError:
    print('Not a number')
```

My task is to 'Calculate the GTIN-8 product code from a seven digit number'
I need a line by line explanation of the code above, please.

Comment: What steps have you taken to figure it out yourself?

Comment: I am going to try to close this question as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some info on enumerate by typing `help(enumerate)`

> enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
>
> Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument. enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:

The `%` operator returns the remainder of `x / y` eg

```
10 / 5 = 2 r 0  |  10 % 5 = 0
7  / 2 = 3 r 1  |  7 % 2 = 1
```

Here is the code explained with comments

```
while True: # Loop will continue until break is called
    try:
        number = input('Enter') #Asks user to input 7 digit number

        # Checks if the length of the input
            # If not 7 characters long
            # Will then ask for input again due to while loop
        if len(str(number)) != 7:
            print('Incorrect')

            # If is 7 chacters long
        if len(str(number)) == 7:
            print('Okay')
            multiplier = [3,1]
            times = ''
            total = 0
            # example input for number '1234567'
            # list(str(number))
            # '1234567' -> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
            for index, digit in enumerate(list(str(number))):
                # index%2 returns either 0 or 1
                # this is used to get 3 or 1 from multiplier
                # depending on if the index is odd or even

                # for first index and digit from example
                # index = 0, digit = '1'
                # total = total + 1 * 3
                total = total + int(digit)*multiplier[index%2]

                # adds the multiplier value from digit * multiplier[index%2]
                # to times as a string. First value is
                # times = times + str(1 * 3) which is 3
                times = times+str(int(digit)*multiplier[index%2])+', '
            # essentially rounds up to nearest 10
            mof10 = total + (10 - total%10)
            # gets the number it was rounded up by
            checkdigit = mof10 - total
            final = str(number) + str(checkdigit)
            print(times[:-1]) # slice the string to return everything except the last value
            print(total)
            print(mof10)
            print(checkdigit)
            print(final)
            break # exit while loop
        # If the convertion from string to int returns an error
        # meaning a non-number was entered into input eg. !@#$
        # print the following, while loop will continue and prompt again
    except ValueError:
        print('Not a number')
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome. I didn't state in the answer, but you'll find some of the `str` conversions are pointless at times since the value from `input` is already a string. Additionally you'll find a times that the best way to understand some code (and debugging) is to put in lots of prints to see what's happening

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I went through and altered your comments a bit, just to make it a bit easier to understand for less experienced coders.  Thank you for the tip, I'm sure it will help a lot! :)

*edit* P.S Not that there was anything wrong with your comments, just wanted to put it into my own words as I thought it would help me remember better.